# How to download all datasets from a CKAN instance using the API?

Tags: api, ckan

I've already tried ckanapi's dump datasets but it seems it only downloads the metadata. Is there a command that downloads the datasets referenced in the download_url field? I can script a download script if needed but I first want to know if it's supported in the API.Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not supported by the CKAN API, so you would need to script it.

Comment: If CKAN is like other systems I'm familiar with, it *only* supports access to the metadata, and not the data itself.  The common procedure is to use the API to identify the objects of interest, get their URL (or otherwise make the request for the object; if may be nearline or offline and need to be staged for access), then you retrieve the data outside of the API.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324712/1308967) shows some Python for downloading via the web UI (using `requests`).